# How to update DAGs in Google Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I want to automate the deployment of DAGs written in a certain repository.

To achieve that I use the gcloud tool and this just imports the DAGs and Plugins according to the documentation.

Now the problem is that when changing the structure of a DAG it is just not possible to get it to load/run correctly in the webinterface. When I use airflow locally I just restart the webserver and everything is fine, however using Cloud Composer I cannot find out how to restart the webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only support uploading DAGs through GCS currently: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/managing-dags

The webserver, which is hosted through GAE, can't be restarted.

Comment: The ability to restart the webserver would be great!  It's often necessary to clean up cruft that somehow sticks around after, for example, clearing up DAGs (or DAG runs) from the DB.